# Range size returns out of range differently for no reason

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a line of code to set the range and write the contents of an array to the sheet.

```
sheetDestination.getRange(1,1,testdata.length,testdata[0].length).setValues(testdata)
```

When this line runs I receive an error:

[image: Error 1]

As you can see in the image the length of the data set is 121830 rows and 14 columns wide.  The error says the data has 15 columns.  So, I modified the code to add 1 to the range width.

```
sheetDestination.getRange(1,1,testdata.length,testdata[0].length+1).setValues(testdata)
```

When I rerun the code I get the following:

[image]

So the array remains the same size and width but now that I added one to make the width 15 it now says the data has 14 columns but the range has 15.

This continues to occur if I use `testdata[0].length`, `14`, `testdata[0].length+1`, or `15`.  This code has run fine for 10 months until today.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

I have tried modifying the code as shown but get a flip flop of results.

Comment: Probably your data array is not rectangular one of the rows is larger than the rest or perhaps the header row is smaller than the rest

Comment: The width of the array is the same between each draw.  what I find interesting is the size switches with the change in width.  I will poll at multiple points in the array to check for that

Comment: Not according to the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a [mcve]. You should describe the relevant parts of the related spreadsheet, this usually imply including sample data, the Apps Script project and including minimal code to reproduce the problem and the errors as text instead of images.

Comment: As mentioned by Cooper one or more of your rows is not 14.  Try `let count=0; testData.forEach( row => { if{ row.length !== 14 } count++; }; console.log( count+" lines are not 14";`

Comment: Something that is typical overseen is that empty / null array elements are skipt by setValues. You should ensure that you use empty strings instead of empty / null array elements.

Comment: You could post a sample of your array that gives you the error and let us look at it.

Comment: Thank you everyone I am putting in a array validation function to see if A row needs padded it will be done there.  I would share a sample but it is proprietary data that I can not release.